# How to connect to Hive in Virtual Box from IntelliJ IDEA with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive, cloudera

I need to connect to Hive in Cloudera CDH 5.8 running in virtualBox , from Spark - scala  program created in IntelliJ on local Windows machine. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly what you need is the HDFS and Hive support. You have 2 options:

1).Create core-site.xml, hive-site.xml where you configure :

core-site property

```
<property>
        <!--<name>fs.defaultFS</name>-->
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>maprfs://cdhdemo:7222</value>
    </property>
```

hive-site properties

```
<property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://cdhdemo:9083</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    </property>
```

2).Or you can configure programmatically with SparkSession:

```
sparkSessionBuilder
      .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://chddemo:9083")
      .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
      .config("fs.defaultFS", "maprfs://chddemo:7222")
      .enableHiveSupport()
```